# How to add libs to Eclipse CDT-managed projects

Tags: c, dependencies, eclipse-cdt

I am using the [Eclipse CDT plugin](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) to write simple C programs, and no where in the documentation can I find info on how to:

- Import [C standard libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) such as `assert.h`, etc.
- Import non-standard, 3rd party libraries, such as `glib`, or even perhaps my own local libraries

In Java-land, to add a jar/lib to your project's build/compile path, one solution is to copy the jar into a `lib/` directory inside the project, right-click it, and then go to `Build Path >> Add to Build Path`. **I'm wondering what the equivalent is for C programs with CDT?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F

For includes: right click on your project and go to Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Compiler >> Includes

you must add the include path for the external library (where the header reside). This information is needed by the Eclipse indexer (code completion etc.) and the compiler

For libraries: right click on your project and go to Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries you must add the library search path (option -L) and the library you want to link against (option -l). This info is needed for the linker.

Comment: Awesome find @rost0031 (+1) - one quick follow up: I'm new to C programming: what is the difference between an "include" and a "library"? Is an include just uncompiled source (that you must then compile along with your app), whereas libraries are already packaged binaries? Thanks again!

Comment: A library is a binary that contains all the symbols of functions that are compiled in.  The header file (includes) contains the associated declarations of those functions and tell you what's in the libraries and allow the linker to link to them.

Comment: See here for more info about libraries and header files: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: Thanks again @rost0031 (+2 for both) - I'm not trying to be difficult here, just want to make sure I fully understand: say I have a library, `fizzbuzz.dll` and a header `fizzbuzz.h`. Are you saying I have to include both of them using the instructions above? Are there situations where I would only include a header file but *not* a library, or vice versa? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you have to include both.  The header file is used by the compiler to find references to the functions you're calling from your exe.  The library is used by the linker to actually find the references to the functions you're calling.  Note that the instructions are different for header files (includes) and libraries.

Comment: I should amend that a little bit: you don't have to include libraries for standard C stuff.  (stdio.h, stdlib.h, etc).  The compiler will automatically link to those correctly.  If, however, you are using some third party library, you have to use both.  Same applies if you are creating a library to use: you have to supply both the header and the dll/so/a file.